# (GCloud SQL) Is there a way to opting in to maintenance notifications via CLI or API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm looking for a way to toggle [this notification](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/set-maintenance-window#opt-in) via gcloud CLI or API call since I need to automate it.
Is there a way of doing it? If not, is this going to be available in the future?
Having a lot of environment is hard to keep track of all of them via UI.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the [Cloud SQL Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/admin-api/) and it seems it is not possible yet. The best way to proceed in this cases is to create a Feature Request in the [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers). I searched for an existing one, but I didn't find any. When submitting a Feature Request, the Engineering team has more visibility of your needs and they can prioritize those requests by the number of users affected.